# apache2 server logs - weird activity?

Tags: hacking

I was going through apache log, and I thought some of the access logs seemed suspicious... I'm not pro, just do server administration as hobby :) so I wonder if I should take some steps...

```
86.138.17.122 - - [20/May/2012:12:53:14 +0200] "\xcb\xaap\xdc\xf9\xba\xec\x0e\x11\xfa\x1d%\x1f\xe9L$\xff\xa6\xe8-\xd2\x11" 501 309 "-" "-"

218.246.22.178 - - [20/May/2012:14:49:22 +0200] "GET /phpMyAdmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1" 404 544 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"

31.176.134.118 - - [21/May/2012:10:32:31 +0200] "\xbe" 501 288 "-" "-"

92.80.76.244 - - [20/May/2012:13:28:19 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
```

I'm not sure about the last one, but first three definitely looks like someone is probing for non existent software on my server.

sudo grep -ir "218.246.22.178" /var/log/apache2/*

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log:218.246.22.178 - - [20/May/2012:14:49:22 +0200] "GET /phpMyAdmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1" 404 544 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1:218.246.22.178 - - [19/May/2012:23:01:55 +0200] "GET /translators.html HTTP/1.1" 404 533 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1:218.246.22.178 - - [20/May/2012:06:30:03 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1" 404 544 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
/var/log/apache2/error.log:[Sun May 20 14:49:22 2012] [error] [client 218.246.22.178] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
/var/log/apache2/error.log.1:[Sat May 19 23:01:55 2012] [error] [client 218.246.22.178] File does not exist: /var/www/translators.html
/var/log/apache2/error.log.1:[Sun May 20 06:30:03 2012] [error] [client 218.246.22.178] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log::443 218.246.22.178 - - [20/May/2012:14:49:19 +0200] "GET /phpMyAdmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1" 401 3233 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.1::443 218.246.22.178 - - [20/May/2012:06:30:02 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1" 401 3232 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty common behavior with any web server exposed to the internet.  Hackers are scanning for vulnerabilities and open proxies.  Check out [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) to block them and [logwatch](http://www.logwatch.org) to monitor for anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

it's vulnerability scanners in search for outdated/exploitable software, most probably scanning large range of addresses. if you keep your stack up-to-date - probably you don't need to worry.

you can try scanning your own site eg using [nikto2](http://cirt.net/nikto2) just to see what sort of requests are sent and possibly find how to secure better your setup.

it's arguable if it's just security-through-obscurity or good practice but you can also configure your default vhost [most scans will call your server by ip address rather than domain name] not to serve any content and respond just with errors or static page.

Answer (score 0):

These are the vulnerability scanner bots often run by research organizations and even attackers. Unless these scans hit and return a HTTP 200 response code, you shouldn't really worry about it.

Some popular scans will leave the following footprint on your server

```
       /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.test0:): 1 Time(s)
```

It's is always recommended to use a firewall on any Internet facing server. You can configure iptables manually or even install csf (ConfigServer Firewall) which is a free and open source firewall and can defend you against various common attacks.